# GL_TIME_ELAPSED equivalent for OpenGL ES (2 or 3)

Tags: opengl-es, elapsedtime

I'm interested in the amount of time it takes the OpenGL ES server to asynchronously run some sequence of commands. The way you solve this with regular OpenGL is to create a query object with the target GL_TIME_ELAPSED; however, OpenGL ES doesn't have the glBeginQuery family of functions. Is there a platform independent way of getting this information accurately with OpenGL ES 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there is no portable way for performance counters in OpenGL ES 2.0. You will need to relay on the tools available for each vendor.

For OpenGLES 3.0 that family of functions have been added. Unfortunately, GL_TIME_ELAPSED is not a valid target for this version.

Please refer to **section 2.13 Asynchronous Queries** (3.02 April 8, 2013): http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/es_spec_3.0.2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenGL ES extensions [GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_disjoint_timer_query.txt), for OpenGL ES 2.0.